# Replace " double quote for ' single quote when it's in an anchor tag

Tags: php, html, str-replace

Hi im creating a xml file but i need to change this.

```
<a href="http://www.whatever.com/" target="_blank">lorem</a>
```

for this

```
<a href='http://www.whatever.com/' target='_blank'>lorem</a>
```

I do it like this:

```
$valFieldBody = "<a href='http://www.whatever.com/' target='_blank'>lorem</a>";
$valFieldBody = str_replace('"', "'", $valFieldBody);
```

but the output is

```
<a href="http://www.whatever.com/" target="_blank">lorem</a>
```

but if i check de source code it shows like

```
<a href='http://www.whatever.com/' target='_blank'>lorem</a>
```

could you please help me

Comment: Show more code. What is `$valFieldBody`? It's working correctly for me.

Comment: How are you originally assigning $valFieldBody?

Comment: Let's hope you don't encounter `<a href="https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/it's">"Not good"</a>`.

Comment: Besides the quote replacement, it seems like you're missing an equals `=` after `target`

Comment: hi i correct somethings in my code

Answer (score 0):

> but the output is … but if i check de source code it shows like

This doesn't make a lot of sense. I think you mean:

- The source code shows `'` around the attribute values
- The DOM Inspector in your browser shows `"` around the attribute values

This is normal and there is nothing you can do about it.

The browser will parse the HTML source code and use it to create a DOM. It will apply rules for optional start and end tags. It will apply error recovery. The DOM might be manipulated by JavaScript. The DOM Inspector will then show a serialised version of that DOM.

It doesn't matter what type of quotes were used around the attribute value in the source code. The browser will always use `"` when it generates the HTML visualisation of the DOM for the DOM inspector.